# Neo4j get the biggest node whose property is smaller than a specific value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Neo4j database, there are many nodes with the same nodeID and different levels, and they are connected through a path. Each time I'm trying to find the node that has the biggest level which is smaller than a specific level `n`. I use the following Cypher query, which starts searching from the most current node with the nodeID `id`.

```
MATCH (:Node{NodeID:id,Current:'true'})-[:type*0..]->(m:Node{NodeID:id}) 
WHERE m.Level < n
RETURN m
ORDER BY m.Level DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And the index I create for this database is as following:

```
CREATE INDEX Nodes FOR(n:Node) ON (n.NodeID, n.Level)
```

However, it's kind of slow especially when the path is long and I need to repeat this process thousands of times. So my question is, is there any better way of implementation and do I need to modify my index to improve the performance? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all `Node`s with the same `NodeID` are in a `type` path rooted at the `Current` node with the same `NodeID`, then the following query should be logically equivalent but faster:

```
MATCH (m:Node)
WHERE m.NodeID = $id AND m.Level < $n
RETURN m
ORDER BY m.Level DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query assumes `id` and `n` are query [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

Comment: Thank you! Is it because in your query it uses index to find the set of nodes instead of traversing the path so it's faster?

Comment: Yes, using just the index is sufficient, and forcing the query to also do path traversals actually slows it down.